# Update issues in SQLIte table

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table in **SQLite Android**

```
table name- score
columns- rank      time      moves
```

I want to increment the ranks of those records whose time is greater than a given time, so I wrote these two codes.

```
ContentValues updatedValue = new ContentValues();
updatedValue.put(KEY_RANK, KEY_RANK+1); //KEY_RANK is a final string "rank" column name
db.update(SCORE, updatedValue, KEY_TIME_ELAPSED + ">=" + time, null); //KEY_TIME_ELAPSED = "time"
```

and other snippet is

```
db.rawQuery("UPDATE "+ TABLE_NAME2 + " SET "+ KEY_RANK + " = " + KEY_RANK + " + 1 WHERE " + KEY_TIME_ELAPSED + " >= " + time + ";", null);
```

In both the cases it is not updating. Can anybody say where am I wrong? Both the snippets are right way to update in my case or not? If one or both are wrong, then please mention which one is wrong?

Comment: is `time` column string?

Comment: time column is integer not string.

Comment: does the query produce any error?

Comment: no error but unexpected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second option is the way to do it. But you need to use **execSQL** because you are not expecting any cursor in return.

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE "+ TABLE_NAME2 + " SET "+ KEY_RANK + " = " + KEY_RANK + 
" + 1 WHERE " + KEY_TIME_ELAPSED + " >= " + time + ";");
```

Comment: But according to the documentation execSQL() should be used when our query is non INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE etc.

Comment: Just give a try, because you are not returning any data.

Answer (score 0):

If `KEY_RANK` is a string, you seems to be trying to set the column name to `string + 1`.

I believe you should first find out the value in that column, then increment it, then set it back.

I am not sure if you can do that in one line.

Answer (score 0):

To debug you could try to do a db query fetching the information that you want to update so that you can see what it is getting. ("SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_NAME2 + " WHERE " + KEY_TIME_ELAPSED + " >= " + time + ";")

Other than that: if you are using beginTransaction(), make sure there is a endTransaction().